# Can I automatically press a button on hitting 'return'-key in a textinput?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently working on an application with Kivy.
On one screen I have a TextInput and a button. I can input text and go to the next screen by pressing the button. 
My question is: Is there a way to just hitting the 'return'-key after typing in your text and automatically press the button without actually touching it?

And a small question on the side: I put

```
focus: True
```

under TextInput so it would focus the textinput immediately when I go to the screen. But it won't work. After some google searching a lot of people said it was a bug, although those comments are fairly old (< 1 year). Is this still bugged or is there a solution to this?

```
TextInput:
    focus: True
    pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'top': .8}
    size_hint: .4, .05
    id: search
    multiline:False

Button:
    text: 'back'
    font_size: 25
    size_hint: .3, .15
    pos_hint: {'x':.15, 'top': .4}
    on_release:
         app.root.current = 'main'
         root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Comment: Try using the `on_text_validate` event in the `TextInput` to trigger the screen change.

Comment: Also, consider using the `on_enter` event of the `Screen` to set the `TextInput` focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this in your `TextInput`:

```
on_text_validate:
     app.root.current = 'main'
     root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

For the auto focus thingy, I use sub-classing.
In the .py I create a new class for `TextInput` and use this instead..

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    """ TextInput with auto-focus
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def set_focus(dt):
            self.focus = True
        Clock.schedule_once(set_focus, .1)
```